# How do I make my game connect to a server without real IP address?

Tags: networking, xna, nat

I'm making an XNA game. When I started, I had a broadband connection with real IP, so I could host servers of any kind without any problem, but now I don't have that connection any more and I want to be able to let players from outside my local network connect to my server again. How do I do that? How do big guys at studios do that?

Comment: Big guys at studios probably got real IP addresses for their servers...

Comment: No, I mean how do they allow for players' clients connect with each other on PCs with no real IPs?

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean like how for example Skype can connect clients behind firewalls?

Comment: My suggestion: In you game, type in several lines of code to make connection to your (php) webpage that returns your server's IP. then your game could make correct connection when initializing.

Comment: My address goes something like 186.123.45.67 and lots of other people have those when not using a real IP connection. There are just no incoming connections from other players when you try such adresses.

Comment: Do you mean that multiple clients of the same ISP have the same public IP ? In that case, I'm afraid there are no straightforward answer to your question.

Comment: Well, I need some answers. I gotta make the servers work again. People like it and Hamachi isn't a very good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there are two ways to connect two clients:

1. Give each client other client's IP address and let them connect to each other.
2. Give each client a mid-server's IP address and tunnel the traffic through it.

First way assumes each client has a real IP address and they both can be a server to one another. Second way is for when one or both clients don't have real IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap option:

- Configure your home router (it does have real, but probably dynamic, IP address) to forward connections on some port of your liking to your server on the local network. Read up on [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) - that's the trick routers use to hide a network behind a single routable IP.
- Setup a [DDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dns) account somewhere, so people can find your game server by name instead of changing IP address.

Expensive options:

- Buy static IP package from your ISP (not always available).
- Deploy your game at a [Hosting Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_hosting_service).